# Do Magento2 support braintree payment method with google pay and apple pay

Tags: magento2, payment, braintree, googlepay

How can i configured Apply pay and Google pay with magento2 using braintree

Answer (score 0):

There is a Official Module available from Paypal.

> https://marketplace.magento.com/paypal-module-braintree.html

Above module have following payment Method:

- PayPal
- ApplePay
- google Pay
- Credit Card

For use above Payment method you need credential from briantree.

You can get sandbox at https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox

Comment: Yes @Pwawan I have already check that module
But after reading review of this module I am not sure i have to use it.https://marketplace.magento.com/paypal-module-braintree.html#bazaarvoice.reviews.tab

Comment: I recently used above module for CC and paypal and they are working. you can try on staging, module is updated in jan 2020, there may be possibility that the fixed previews issues.